# how to find macd and signal for multiple stocks in python using yfinance and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I have the below code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

start=dt.datetime.today()-dt.timedelta(160)
end=dt.datetime.today()
clprice=pd.DataFrame(yf.download("FB MSFT AMZN GOOG GM", start=start, end=end))
clprice=clprice.dropna()
def macd(DF,a,b,c):
  df=DF.copy()
  df['MA Fast']=df['Adj Close'].ewm(span=a, min_periods=a).mean()
  df['MA Slow']=df['Adj Close'].ewm(span=b, min_periods=b).mean()
  df["MACD"]=df['MA Fast']-df['MA Slow']
  df['Signal']=df.MACD.ewm(span=c, min_periods=c).mean()
  df["Histrogram"]=df.MACD-df.Signal
  df=df.dropna()
  df.iloc[:,[4,8,9,10]].plot()
  plt.savefig("msftmacdsignal.png")
  return df


d=macd(clprice, 12,26,9)
```

I am trying to create a function that takes a dataframe and returns MACD and signal. when I am using a single ticker I have no problem it is giving me the appropriate results. When I am using more than one stock like in this case "FB MSFT AMZn GOOG GM" i am getting this error:

```
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer refers to code as provided in question:

```
import pandas as pd 
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

start=dt.datetime.today()-dt.timedelta(160)
end=dt.datetime.today()
clprice=pd.DataFrame(yf.download("FB MSFT AMZN GOOG GM", start=start, end=end))
clprice=clprice.dropna()
def macd(DF,a,b,c):
  df=DF.copy()
  df['MA Fast']=df['Adj Close'].ewm(span=a, min_periods=a).mean()
  df['MA Slow']=df['Adj Close'].ewm(span=b, min_periods=b).mean()
  df["MACD"]=df['MA Fast']-df['MA Slow']
  df['Signal']=df.MACD.ewm(span=c, min_periods=c).mean()
  df["Histrogram"]=df.MACD-df.Signal
  df=df.dropna()
  df.iloc[:,[4,8,9,10]].plot()
  plt.savefig("msftmacdsignal.png")
  return df
```

To call single ticker, for example "FB" I use:

```
macd(clprice.xs('FB', level=1, axis=1), 12,26,9)
```

So for mulitple tickers, with no change in Your `macd` function:

```
for ticker in clprice.columns.get_level_values(1).unique():
    macd(clprice.xs(ticker, level=1, axis=1), 12,26,9)
```

Please notice columns are multilevel, so `get_levelvalues` is used.
After running above code the chart per ticker is produced.

Comment: i am getting this error:raise IndexError(
IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2


Comment: Did You run exactly the same code with the same tickers FB MSFT AMZN GOOG GM and date range?

Comment: Good to hear it :-) If itsok consider accepting it as an answer please.